# Print List<object> on papper c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Can someone show me how in a simple way print my list. 
I cant find example how to do that.

Every examples which i found they were not understood.
And almost everyone show to start with:

```
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDlg.Document = printDoc;
```

or other way which throw exception. This throw exception `printDlg` `dont contains Document`.

Comment: That's because the samples you find are for WinForms, and you're using WPF. See duplicate for a starting point.

Comment: thanks, i was looking for on StackOverFlow but didnt found this.